# How to remove "CHAPTER" for unnumbered chapters in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I wonder how I could remove word "CHAPTER" for unnumbered chapters in ToC. I do the following:

```
\chapter*{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}
\label{chap:intro}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}}
```

I also tried to do this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{}{\protect\numberline{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}}
```

It works, but the problem with that is removing dots and space between name of the chapter and number of the page - number goes right next to the name of the chapter.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,russian]{extreport}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=1cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{gostfigure}{Рисунок #2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{gost}{~---~}
\captionsetup{labelsep=gost}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=gostfigure}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace{0.38\textwidth} \bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\mbox{}\hfill \\ \mbox{}\hfill{\footnotesize Стр.}\vspace{-2.5em}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} }
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\hspace{31pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\hspace{11pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{-1mm}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % задать глубину оглавления — до section включительно

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter}
{\MakeUppercase{ГЛАВА} \thechapter}
{8pt}   
{\bfseries}{}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}{}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}{}

\linespread{1.3}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm} % Times New Roman
\frenchspacing

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}

\pretolerance1000

\begin{document}

\def\contentsname{ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ}
\def\chaptername{ГЛАВА}

\newpage
\include{title}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{ГЛАВА}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{СПИСОК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫХ ИСТОЧНИКОВ}


\chapter*{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}
\label{chap:intro}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}

    ...

\end{document}
```

I don't see anything wrong, all packages do their job, if I am not mistaken...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A full MWE is needed here.  The behavior you describe is non-standard, which means you added some package or code which is causing your problem.  You might even start by simply removing packages one at a time until the problem goes away.

Comment: I added full MWE. Unfortunately, I do not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: This is not a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). We cannot reproduce the problem with some lines of code from the document preamble. Nevertheless: Change `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}}` into `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}ВВЕДЕНИЕ}` or `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ВВЕДЕНИЕ}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes, they work, but the reason why I am asking this is that I want to remove word "CHAPTER" from ToC for this unnumbered chapter.

Comment: Do not understand your comment. Does one of the changes solve your problem (after at least two LaTeX runs) or do they not? Once again: Please show us a minimal **but working** example from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke they dont. I added full working example.

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}` is not a font attribute …

Comment: Use something like `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}` and `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} }` and `\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}`.